# How to run a block of code without blocking the application in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, runtime, sleep, execution

I have an application that allows you to use a Python startup script. I want to run one part of the code after the application is fully initialized, but there is no way to know this.

I used `time.sleep()` but then the application hangs till it executes that code. I also transferred the code to another file and used `execfile` but same result.

So basically I want something like this:

```
startup script:
    my code
    code to run 5 seconds later
```

What's the easiest way to achieve this? Do I have to use threading for this?

Comment: What application are you using?

Comment: Maya 3d application.

Comment: I think threading is the easiest way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691576/async-wait-non-blocking-wait-in-python

Comment: @ZZY: I actually tried this an hour ago but it still blocks it when I use sleep in the other method. I don't know why that's not concerned by its own thread but I assume maybe the app itself is encapsulating everything to run in a single thread?

Comment: Maybe you can try [executeInMainThreadWithResult](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/index.html?url=files/Python_Python_and_threading.htm,topicNumber=d30e727083) or [executeDeferred](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/pymel/generated/functions/pymel.mayautils/pymel.mayautils.executeDeferred.html). I don't have Maya environment to test

Answer (score 1):

How about at the end of your `startup script` it writes to or creates a log file contains something like `'initiation complete'`.

So another code will check if the file is created or the text is written after each x millisecond and then execute the rest of it.

Comment: Thanks but who will run that code that checks for the file? Because if I start it and then that code hangs till the file is written, the app will still hang till then.

Comment: @JoanVenge, you can throw the loop check for the log file to another thread or process, so the rest of your program will run without being blocked.

Comment: Thanks I tried the thread thing but it didn't work. I will research the process thing.